# How can I insert an MD5("value" + CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) using prepared statements?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, md5, sql-insert

I'm doing this:

```
String columns = "UserHash,EMail,Name,Gender,BirthYear,Birthday,MaritalStatus,UserID,ReferralUser,Likes";

String sql = "INSERT INTO Users ("+ columns+") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        byte[] bytesOfUserHash = user.getId().getBytes("UTF-8");

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] userHash = md.digest(bytesOfUserHash);

        stmt  = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setBytes(1,userHash);
        stmt.setString(2, user.getEmail());
        stmt.setString(3, user.getName());
        stmt.setInt(4, user.getGender().value());
        stmt.setString(5, birthday.split("-")[0]);
        stmt.setString(6, birthday);
        stmt.setInt(7, user.getRelationshipStatus().value());
        stmt.setString(8, user.getId());
        stmt.setString(9, referraluser);
        stmt.setString(10, likesjson);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
```

All values are being inserted except for `userHash`, so the query is succeeding.  What should I check?

Also, note I'm just hashing the userid right now, but I would like to hash the userid + `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

**UPDATE:**
As a sanity check, I just tried tossing a string into the UserHash column as it is of type VARCHAR(45) and that's not working either.  Something is obviously amiss independent of the MD5 issue.

Comment: What does your table contain for that column after the insert?

Comment: It contains nothing (NULL).

Comment: Is it possible your `columns` are not correct?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: added columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL's built in MD5 function and only pass userId as parameter

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Users ("+ columns+") VALUES (MD5(CONCAT(?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

    stmt  = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setInt(1,user.getId());
    ...
```

Comment: That looks pretty close to my original attempt.  However, it's not working either.  UserHash column is still null in the table.

Comment: I was not redeploying my updated code.  This is the correct answer to my original question.